# CSS: Create an inset, rounded box-shadow

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a box shadow just like shown in the image:

[image]

As you can see the shadow is rounded. I tried it with CSS like this:

```css
 .rottweiler {
      width: 600px;
      height: 300px;
      background-image: url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn-origin-etr.akc.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/12224942/Rottweiler-On-White-10.jpg');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: top;
      border: 1px solid silver;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    }
```

```html
<div class="rottweiler"></div>
```

I want the shadow to be more like a circle, how do I do that?

Comment: looks like a radial-gradient for me https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient()

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks! Didn't know about this. I got it working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.rottweiler {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle, transparent, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)), url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn-origin-etr.akc.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/12224942/Rottweiler-On-White-10.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top;
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="rottweiler"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`radial-gradient`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient())

```css
.rottweiler {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle, transparent, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn-origin-etr.akc.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/12224942/Rottweiler-On-White-10.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top;
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="rottweiler"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this pattern using **CSS Radial Gradients**

**SYNTAX**

```
background-image: radial-gradient(shape size at position, start-color, ..., last-color);
```

For more info: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients_radial.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
 #grad {
      min-height: 100vh;
      background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at center center,  #4d4d4d 5%,  #252525 , black 100%);
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="grad"></div>


</body>
</html>
```